# How to make it so a song starts from the beginning for every player?

Tags: lua, roblox

The script picks a random song from the list and plays it when a player joins. It works perfectly but when another user joins, it syncs the song for the second player with the first player's. I am trying to figure out a way so that I can make it so when ever a user joins, the song starts from the beginning for that user.
Code:

```
--Script Created by Sheasu
local songs = script.Parent
local tablee = {}
local lastsong = nil

for i,v in pairs(songs:GetChildren()) do
    if v:IsA("Sound") then
        table.insert(tablee,v)
    end
end

while true do
    for a,c in pairs(tablee) do
        local chosensong = tablee[math.random(1,#tablee)]
        repeat wait() chosensong = tablee[math.random(1,#tablee)] until chosensong ~= lastsong
        lastsong = chosensong
        chosensong:Play()
        chosensong.Ended:Wait()
        chosensong:Stop()
    end
    wait()
end
```

Comment: Is this in a Script or a LocalScript? Where are the Sound objects that are put into this table located? Are they in the Workspace?

Comment: It is a script, the sound objects and the script are both located in a folder in workspace called Sounds.

Comment: Try moving the contents of this Script to a LocalScript in StarterPlayerScripts

Comment: I moved the script to StaterPlayerScripts and it did not work. I also tried moving the songs and the folder to StaterPlayerScripts but it still didn't work. No song was playing.

Answer (score -1):

You could run it in a local script, that should work.